# PDF files get downloaded twice - IE8

Tags: java, internet-explorer, jakarta-ee, pdf, adobe

I am facing an issue while streaming PDF file on a Java EE web application over HTTPS connection.  I am using an IFRAME to display the PDF file. I display the pdf using an ajax call to the server.

**I have noticed that PDF streaming got downloaded twice just on Internet Explorer**

- I saw that by using Wireshark to measure the frame size, and saw it is the double of the requested PDF file size.
- Also used HttpWatch Basic, to see the PDF got downloaded twice.

Is there any known issue on Internet Explorer about that?  What is the workaround?
For information I have this issue using Acrobat Reader 9 on Internet Explorer 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a well known fact, documented by Microsoft in a [knowledge base article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/293792/en-us).

The article has a workaround. But I recommend against implementing it since it's too Windows specific and since ActiveX is a thing of the past.

Do you have an problem with that behavior? Normally, it's not a problem. If you generate the PDF on the fly and it's expensive to produce it, cache it.

Comment: Hello, my PDF file is sent as a binary stream. And as it is said on microsoft website, their workaround doesn't work with binary strams.

Answer (score 0):

Just wild guesses:

- That would indicate that you have an URL like "/xxx/pdf" yielding a PDF and IE is invoking something like "/xxx/pdf/favicon.ico" yielding the PDF too.
- Or (unlikely) maybe a HTTP POST with "...?x=2".
- Are the headers okay? Content-Type: application/x-pdf, Content-Length correct. Maybe you have a (erroneous) Content-Disposition?

Comment: Thx for the answer. But the displayed url contains .pdf. HTTP POST is ok with an ajax request. Headers parameters already checked. Seems fine too.

Comment: Ah, _Ajax_. Googling after **ajax twice internet explorer** gave me at least three similar issues in stackoverflow.